# Transforming Binary data

Tags: r, binary

I have a dataframe that only consists of 0 and 1. So for each individual instead of having one column with a factoral value (ex. low price, 4 rooms) I have

```
      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
1     0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
2     1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
3     0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
4     0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

How can I transform the dataset in R, so that I create new columns (#number of rooms) and give the position of the 1 (in the 4th column) a vhigh value? 
I have multiple expenatory varibales I need to do this for. the 21 columns are representing 6 variables for 1000+ observations. should be something like this

```
     PurchaseP.   NumberofRooms ...
1.      vhigh.         4
2.      low.           4
3.      vhigh.         1
4.      vhigh.         2
```

Just did it for the first 2 epxlenatory varibales here, but essentially it repeats like this with each explenatory variable has 3-4 possible factoral values.

V1:V4 = purchase price, V5:V8 = number of rooms,V9:V11 = floors, and so on

In my head something like this could work

1. create a if statemt to give each 1 a value depending on column position, ex. if  value in V4=1 then name "vhigh". and do this for each Vx
2. Then combine each column V1:V4, V5:V8, V9:V11 (depending on if it has 3-4 possible factoral/integer values) while ignoring 0 values.

Would this work, or is there a simpler approach? How would one code this in R?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that should work for you. I wrote a function, which will take as arguments your data.frame, the columns representing one of your variables of interest (e.g. purchase price is stored in columns 1 to 4), and the names of the levels you would like as a result. The function will then return the result you requested. You'll need to write this out for the 6 variables you are interested in.

I'll simulate some data and illustrate the approach.

```r
df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(c(0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), 2), 
                        nrow = 4, byrow = T))
df
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
#> 1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
#> 2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
#> 3  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
#> 4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

We'll say that the first four columns are the purchase price in v.low to v.high, and the second four are the number of rooms (1:4). We'll write a function that takes this information as arguments and returns the result:

```r
rangeToCol <- function(df, # Your data.frame
                       range, # the columns that incode the category of interest
                       lev.names # The names of the category levels
                       ) {
  tdf <- df[range]
  lev.names[unlist(apply(tdf, 1, function(rw){which(rw==1)}))]
}

new.df <- data.frame(PurchaseP = rangeToCol(df, 1:4,  
                                 c('vlow','low','high','vhigh')),
                     NumberofRooms = rangeToCol(df, 5:8, c(1:4)))
new.df
#>   PurchaseP NumberofRooms
#> 1     vhigh             1
#> 2      vlow             4
#> 3     vhigh             1
#> 4      vlow             4
```